# Prevent npm start if node version mismatch

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

I have a project that needs Node >= V14 and would like to prevent npm script execution if node version does not match.

Using `.npmrc` and `engines` in `package.json`, I can prevent `npm install` from running if node version does not match.

However, is there any way to prevent `npm start` from executing if appropriate node version is not found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** NPM does not provide a built-in feature to achieve this.

---

#### Solution:

However your requirement can be met by utilizing a custom node.js helper script:

1. Save the following `check-version.js` script in the root of your project directory, i.e. save it at the same level where *package.json* resides

   **check-version.js**

   ```js
   const MIN_VERSION = 14;
   const nodeVersion = process.version.replace(/^v/, '');
   const [ nodeMajorVersion ] = nodeVersion.split('.');

   if (nodeMajorVersion < MIN_VERSION) {
     console.warn(`node version ${nodeVersion} is incompatible with this module. ` +
         `Expected version >=${MIN_VERSION}`);
     process.exit(1);
   }
   ```
2. In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* define your `start` script as follows:

   **package.json**

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "start": "node check-version && echo \"Running npm start\""
   },
   ....
   ```

   **Note** Replace the `echo \"Running npm start\"` part (above) with whatever your current `start` command is.

---

**Explanation:**

- In `check-version.js` we obtain the Node.js version string via [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version) and remove the `v` prefix using the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

  <sub>**Note:** You may prefer to use [`process.versions.node`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version) instead of `replace` to obtain the version string without the prepended `v`.</sub>
- Next we obtain the Major version only from the version string and assign it to the `nodeMajorVersion` variable.
- Finally in the `if` statement we check whether the `nodeMajorVersion` is less than the expected minimum node.js version (`MIN_VERSION`). If it is less than the expected version we warn the user and call the [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) method with the exit code as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your `start` does, but if it's your code:

```
if (process.versions.node.split('.')[0] < 14) process.exit(1)
```