# How to print a friendly error when node runtime does not support ecmascript modules?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I've written a node.js command line application that uses [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html), [top-level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await), and [nullish coalescing operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) so it requires at least node 14.

Older node.js versions can't even parse the script and throw a SyntaxException before evaluating anything. I want to print a friendly error telling users to upgrade to a supported version but I can't get around syntax errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
# entry.cjs
if (process.version.split('.', 1)[0].slice(1) < 14) {
  console.log('too old')
  process.exit(1)
}
import './index.js'
```

```
$ node8 entry.cjs
import './index.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

If I switch to `require('./index.js')` then it fails with modern runtimes because you cannot `require()` an ES module.

```
$ node16 entry.cjs
entry.cjs:6
require('./index.js')
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module index.js from entry.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in entry.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (entry.cjs:6:1) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I thought an dynamic import expression would work because it would only be evaluated after parsing and  after the version check, but that is a reserved keyword even in node 8

```
$ node8 entry.cjs
node entry.cjs
entry.cjs:6
import('./index.js')
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Answer (score 1):

#### With NPM

You could define a `package.json` file and have your start command check the node version first, and then run your script

Example from [another SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67831958/prevent-npm-start-if-node-version-mismatch):

```js
// package.json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node check-version.js && node index.js"
  },
  //...
}

// check-version.js
const MIN_VERSION = 14;
const nodeVersion = process.version.replace(/^v/, '');
const [ nodeMajorVersion ] = nodeVersion.split('.');

if (nodeMajorVersion < MIN_VERSION) {
  console.warn(`node version ${nodeVersion} is incompatible with this module.`, `Expected version >= ${MIN_VERSION}`);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Then `npm start` would gracefully fail if the version is lower than required and run as expected if not. (You could define another name for the script, i.e.: `npm run entry`)

---

#### Without NPM

If you do not wish to use npm/yarn, you could achieve the same result via .sh:

1. Create `entry.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   node check-version.js && node index.js
   ```
2. `chmod 755 entry.sh`
3. `./entry.sh`

Comment: I'm not using npm or yarn, this is a CLI users will install on their PATH.

Comment: The shell wrapper would work but I'm not thrilled with spawning two additional processes

Comment: The shell wrapper can be `node -r ./check-version.csj index.js`

Comment: About the extra node process, you could also translate the check-version.js logic into bash (Run node -v, process the output)

Answer (score -1):

I eventually used a shell wrapper

```
#!/bin/bash
PROGDIR=$(dirname "$0")
node -r "$PROGDIR"/check-version.cjs "$PROGDIR"/index.js
```

This could be written as a shebang line if the os supports multiple shebang arguments.